# does anyone know of any o-words or go-words which are absolutely neutral?

Tags: words, honorifics, prefixes, bikago, lexicalization

Does anyone know of any o-words or go-words which are absolutely neutral (have no nuances of being polite / courteous / respectful / womanly / cute etc etc)?

The only ones I'm aware of currently is おちゃ and ごはん

**Update**

Does anyone know of any o-words or go-words that when the お or ご is omitted, becomes another word or not a word altogether?

The only ones I'm aware of currently is ごはん

Comment: I wonder if おまえ counts.

Comment: I've heard that Omae used to be polite way back when so that o would be polite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a list of neutral o- and go- words:

> - お手玉 'small bag for juggling'
> - おみくじ 'written oracle'
> - お冠 'being angry' [Not crown]
> - お目玉 'being angry' [Not eye ball]
> - お新香 'pickle'
> - おにぎり 'rice ball' [Not sushi]
> - おむすび
> - おこぼれ 'something positive gained (unexpectedly) from someone else' [Not falling off]
> - お裾分け 'a portion given away'
> - お下がり 'used thing (clothes, etc.) often given from a senior to a junior sibling' [Not going down]
> - お流れ 'cancel' [Not current]
> - おあずけ
> - お手上げ
> - お手
> - おかわり
> - お手付き
> - お年玉
> - お多福

Comment: heys btw just to clarify, do you mean that for お手玉, おみくじ, お新香, お裾分け we can remove the を and the meaning would still be the same but for the rest we couldn't?

Comment: @Pacerier No. For all of them, if you remove `お`, it would either not be a word used in present Japanese, or a word with a different meaning. For the ones that I put explanation in brackets, there is a word without `お` with a different meaning.

Comment: I have been told a few times that お金 is an example of a 'neutral' word with お on the front, but since it works fine as 金 by itself, I guess that it doesn't apply.

Comment: These are all historical changes, and some words are under transition now. But I think for 'お金', 'お' still has politeness.

Comment: @sawa Btw I was wondering when we use "お休み" to mean that someone has taken a day off school/work, is the "お" in "お休み" considered neutral, or does it carry *respect* ?

Comment: @Pacerier Originally, it was polite, but as it became a fixed expression, it lost politeness.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know what you mean by “absolutely neutral (have no nuances of being polite / courteous / respectful / womanly / cute etc etc).”

Saying お茶{ちゃ} is definitely more polite to the listener than saying 茶{ちゃ}.  The same applies to お冷{ひや} in Dave M G’s answer: it is a polite form of a rarer word 冷 (ひや; often written as 冷や).

ご in ご飯{はん}'cannot be simply removed (because 飯 read as はん is not a word in itself), but ご飯 is at least more polite than 飯{めし}.  I do not think that there is any reason to believe that ご in ご飯 means anything other than politeness.

phirru mentioned おまえ in a comment on the question.  I do not know the etymology of お前{まえ}, but I guess that お in お前 originally comes from the same お meaning politeness.

Comment: This is actually a good question. If you think about the origin, these `お` and `御` used to be polite, but over the time, the version without them disappeared, and these prefixes on them lost their polite meaning. This is a usual thing in language change. The fact that `飯` (han) and `前` (mae) is not said in the relevant sense is the criterion that `御` in `御飯` and `お` in `お前` do not express polite anymore. With `お茶`, I agree that `お` still expresses politeness. Do you really say `冷` 'hiya' in the relevant sense?

Comment: @sawa: I wrote my opinion in the answer.  I do not agree with your opinion that the prefixes lost their polite meaning in the case where the versions without the prefixes disappeared.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the vagueness of the question. i've edited it

Comment: For anybody reading these comments and interested in the process mentioned by sawa, you can get an introduction from reading the Wikipedia article on ***[lexicalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/lexicalization)***.

Answer (score 2):

お冷{ひや} for a "cold drink of water", at a restaurant, is one.

As an updated answer to your updated question, お冷 doesn't become a different word or a non-word if the お is omitted. I don't think that circumstance exists.

However, having wondered myself if 冷, by itself, would be understood in a restaurant context, I've tried it and can say from experience that waitstaff will look at you quizzically if you drop the お.

お冷, like most お and ご words, has become a conventional set phrase. Changing it up is just weird.

Comment: heys btw will ひや itself  work/not work
?

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't heard of お冷, and according to [this page](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1328601828) at least, お冷 is more of a word that the waiter uses? Or is it different to お水 somehow?